# How do I edit a line created by an installer

Tags: linux, bash, python, anaconda

So I've been trying to install Anaconda on elementary os. I used the steps found on this website http://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/. And got the following error.

> bash: /home/anton/.bashrc: line 171: syntax error near unexpected token `added'
>
> bash: /home/anton/.bashrc: line 171: esac# added by Anaconda3 5.3.0 installer'

apparently this means that on line 171 it should be

> esac #added by Anaconda3 5.3.0 installer'

but if this line was added by the installer I don't know what I can do to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Was this the last line in .bashrc before installing anaconda?
If so you could try adding a newline at the end of the .bashrc before installing anaconda.

The part in the Anaconda3-5.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh that appends code to the .bashrc (line 719...736)

```
  cat <<EOF >> "$BASH_RC"
# added by Anaconda3 5.3.0 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="\$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '$PREFIX/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ \$? -eq 0 ]; then
    \\eval "\$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "$PREFIX/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "$PREFIX/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \\export PATH="$PREFIX/bin:\$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
EOF
```

Comment: This came up after I closed and reopened the terminal. I haven't been able to find the line with esac# in it let alone try and change it.

Comment: The first thing the anaconda installer appends to the .bashrc file is "#added by Anaconda...." and this should start on a new line

Comment: Sorry I think, I misunderstood your comment. Are you sure you edit the right .bashrc file? Have you tried a different editor.